# How do I make three attack systems so that there is a rock-paper-scissors distribution, but equal average?

Tags: mathematics, combat

In the game, there are three attack systems: Strength-based, Magic-based, and Psionic-based.

The damage each type deals will be multiplied by their own modifier. The one for strength I have come up with is ((3 d6 rolls)*10+Luck)/100.

How can I make similar calculations (willing to not use the one I came up with, but would like to do something similar) so that the Strength one beats the Magic one more often than not, the Magic one beats the Psionic one more often than not, and the Psionic one beats the strength one more often than not, by roughly the same amount on average.

I know that this sort of thing is possible.

If you take four spinners with six numbers, (5,4,3,5,4,3) loses 2 out of 3 to (6,6,0,0,6,6), which loses two out of three to (7,1,7,1,7,1), which loses 2 out of 3 to (2,2,8,8,2,2), which loses 2 out of 3 to (5,4,3,5,4,3).

Comment: Do you know which of the two bases will be engaging in combat?  If you know that for Strength > Magic, you could always calculate the values for each and multiply by some normalized constant to allow you to get a distributions of wins the way you want right?

Comment: The spinner example you describe is often known by the name of [Intransitive or Non-Transitive Dice](https://www.google.ca/search?q=intransitive+dice) -
 see this [DataGenetics article](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/july12012/index.html) for a good intro. I made an [applet where you can quickly explore the relationships of many such dice](http://dmgregory.ca/misc/diceexplorer.html), in case it's of interest. :)

Comment: Is DMGregory's Idea enough? Or do you need real D6 or another distribution function?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt I'd prefer it that the formula of attack doesn't change based on who the attackers are.

Comment: @DMGregory If you could somehow use that program to give red three dice, blue three dice, and green three dice, so that it was possible for any player to get any number between 3 and 18, red beats blue as often as blue beats green and green beats red, that'd be so far above my expectations that I'd upvote it and give it the tick on the spot.

Comment: The problem with not having the formula change is that you expect A > B > C and therefor C > A can't exist right?  You need an extra constant to ensure that if C attacks A, you can have C > A.  Instead you'd want things to look like A * SOME_CONSTANT > B if attacking B.  B * SOME_CONSTANT > C if attacking C.  etc.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt [6,5,5,5,0,0] wins 55.56% of the time against [7,4,4,3,2,1], which wins 55.17% of the time against [7,7,4,1,1,1], which wins 55.56% of the time against [6,5,5,5,0,0]. However, I'd rather have something like that that worked with three dice each, and adding up to all numbers from 3-18 all be possible in each trio.

Answer (score 2):

In case the two parties each select an attack type (S/M/P) before the attack, you could do this:

Both parties roll two dice.

If they both use the same attack type (S vs S, M vs M or P vs P), then the damage dealt by each is the lowest valued dice.

If either party chose a dominant attack type (S over M, M over P or P over S), then that party deals according to highest valued dice.

That does result in a dramatic advantage though:
77% chance of win for the dominant attack over a 12% chance of win for the other.

To temper that advantage, you could instead let dominant party take best of three dice, versus dominated party take best of 2 dice.

Comment: That's a good idea and I like it, however if at all possible I'd like the formula to not factor in the opponent party.